# Towers of Hanoi - giving help to the user mid game

Tags: java, towers-of-hanoi

I have successfully built the Tower of Hanoi game in java with user interactivity.

However, I also want to add a feature where if the user asks for hint, the program does the next move for the user in the most efficient way.

I know the game can be solved using recursion but as far as I know, I can't use recursion mid-game to give answers.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: You should still be able to use recursion mid-game to give answers. A robust algorithm should be able to discover the correct solution even if you're not starting with the board in the traditional starting state.

Comment: Alternatively, there is a simple rule-based solution to that puzzle; you might be able to take advantage of that.