# Solving Tower of Hanoi with arbitrary input

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I want to solve the Tower of Hanoi for an **arbitrary (but valid) input**.
For example I have a game with 3 discs:

```
A    B    C

|    |    |
|    |    1
|    3    2
```

The iterative and the recursive algorithms given on wikipedia fail with this input. The recursive stops in a wrong position or attempts illegal moves and the iterative one does not terminate.

Is there an "easy" algorithm to solve this?
The only other question I found is [Towers of Hanoi - giving help to the user mid game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668424/towers-of-hanoi-giving-help-to-the-user-mid-game) and both answers were not helpful.

Comment: You are likely to get more help if you specify the language you are using and include the code which fails.

Comment: Sorry, but your comment is not helpful, since the question is language agnostic. My implementations are correct, but the algorithms don't solve my problem.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/050628660 (sorry, it is behind a pay-wall)

Answer (score 1):

For the solution on Wikipedia: they're only for moving the stack from one pin to another, not for any input. You might consider using some path-finding algorithm (works for any valid input and expected output).

```
define state := a state of the hanoi tower (the positions of all elements on the pins).

define listMoves := returns a list of all valid moves that can made from the specified state

define solve:
    input: state start , state end
    output: void

    list visited
    list nextStates
    add(nextStates , start)

    while NOT isEmpty(nextStates)
        state s = remove(nextStates , 0)

        if s == end
             return

        add(visited , s)

        for state n : listMoves(s)
            if NOT contains(visited , n)
                add(nextStates , n)
                add(visited , n)
```

This is just some simple BFS. You could aswell use Dijkstra's or A*.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "some path-finding algorithm"? Otherwise your answer is not really helping.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple but not very efficient answer:**

First run the algorithm on the smaller problem to get to a standard bigger one, then run the algorithm on the bigger problem.
In the given example, you would run `SolveHanoi(2, C, B)` and then `SolveHanoi(3, B, A)` to move all three discs from the given state to A.

**More efficient solution:**

Notice that the recursive solution (if my memory serves me right) runs the algorithm on a smaller problem, moves one disc, and then runs the algorithm on the same small problem, with a slight variation.

What I suggest you try (or check in some way), is running the original algorithm, but not all of it - just the part that needs to be run from the state you are given.

**Clarification:**

Looking at the given example, think of this:
If there was a game where all discs were on poll B and you were required to move them to A, the algorithm would:
1. Move discs 1 & 2 to C.
2. Move 3 to A.
3. Move 1 & 2 to A.

The input you were given is the state after stage #1.

Your solution should do this:
1. Realize what is a possible initial state (not too many option since there are three polls to begin with).
2. Run the recursive algorithm in NOT-REAL-OP mode (without actually doing any moves) until you reach the given state.
3. Continue running the algorithm in REAL-OP mode.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: It thought of this already. The problem with this is, that the recursive algorithm would never reach this state, because the state (in the example) is not on the fastet path to the solution.

Comment: For the problem of 3 discs at B that need to be moved to A, it is on the fastest path.

Comment: @Seb: Also, please see edited answer with a simple, inefficient answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd say there's an "easy" algorithm: a brute force, recursive search of all possible moves until you find the target state. That's "easy" as an algorithm, but may require some time to process, depending on the size of your problem. Also, for n piles using m discs there's n^m possible states, so larger puzzles may hit memory problems.

For example, using [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm):

- Dijkstra's "graph" is the collection of all possible board states.
- Dijkstra's "node" is a single board state.
- The "distance" from one node to the next is the number of moves
  required to get there.

Then you could use the "[infinite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Practical_optimizations_and_infinite_graphs)" optimisation to avoid having to enumerate all states in the initialisation phase.

Coming down to practicalities, the main question then seems to me to be "what is the best way of storing the board state?". I'm using a slightly different example here for clarity (3 piles, 4 discs):

```
A    B    C
|    |    |
|    3    1
|    4    2
```

A simple approach which models the board would be to have an integer array for each pile, each containing the numbers of the discs on that pile:

```
A -> []
B -> [3,4]
C -> [2,1]
```

However, my first instinct would be to go the other way round, and just store a single array containing the pile each disc is on (1 is on C, 2 is on C, 3 is on B, 4 is on B):

```
Discs = [C,C,B,B]       // four entries, one for each disc
```

This entirely captures the board state in a single array, and is easy to compare (you could just store a single string here if you wanted: "CCBB").

To calculate the next possible moves, just run through the array: the first time you see a letter, that is the smallest disc on that pile (nothing is on A, 3 is at the top of B, 1 is at the top of C):

```
Piles = [0,3,1]        // three entries - one for each pile
```

Then you can move any entry to an empty pile (0) or a larger number, so possible moves are:

```
3 -> 0 : B -> A : Discs[3] = "A"  // move disc 3 from B to A giving [C,C,A,B]
1 -> 0 : C -> A : Discs[1] = "A"  // move disc 1 from C to A giving [A,C,B,B]
1 -> 3 : C -> B : Discs[1] = "B"  // move disc 1 from C to B giving [B,C,B,B]
```

I think if I actually wrote this I'd probably end up caching the smallest disc on each pile in the board state to save recalculating it each time, but the idea is the same.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Tower of hanoi iterative solution
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TowerOfHanoi {

```
private static int SIZE = 5;

private class stack {

    stack(int size) {
        dataElements = new int[size];
    }
    int[] dataElements;

    int top = -1;

    private void push(int element) {
        dataElements[++top] = element;
    }

    private int pop() {
        if(top==-1) {
            return -1;
        }
        int topEle = dataElements[top];
        dataElements[top]=0;
        top --;
        return topEle;
    }

    private int top() {
        if(top==-1) {
            return -1;
        }
        return dataElements[top];
    }

    private boolean isEmpty() {
        return top == -1;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    towerOfHanoi(SIZE);
}

private static void towerOfHanoi(int number) {
    initialize(number);
    if(number % 2 == 0) {
        solveEven(number);
    } else {
        solveOdd(number);
    }
}

private static int recentMoved = -1;

private static stack source = new TowerOfHanoi().new stack(SIZE);
private static stack intermediate = new TowerOfHanoi().new stack(SIZE);
private static stack destination = new TowerOfHanoi().new stack(SIZE);

private static void solveEven(int number) {

    while(destination.top < number-1) {
        if(!movePlates(source, intermediate, destination)) {
            if(!movePlates(intermediate,destination,source)) {
                if(!movePlates(destination, source, intermediate)){
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}



private static boolean movePlates(stack from , stack dest1 ,stack dest2) {
    boolean movedPlate = false;
    if(from.top()== recentMoved) {
        return movedPlate;
    }
    if((!from.isEmpty()) && from.top()<(dest1.top()==-1?10000:dest1.top())) {
        dest1.push(from.pop());
        recentMoved=dest1.top();
        movedPlate = true;
    }
    else if((!from.isEmpty()) && from.top()<(dest2.top()==-1?10000:dest2.top())){
        dest2.push(from.pop());
        recentMoved=dest2.top();
        movedPlate = true;
    }
    if(movedPlate)
        display();
    return movedPlate;
}

private static void display() {
    Arrays.stream(source.dataElements).forEach(System.out::print);
    //.stream().fl.forEach(System.out::print);
    System.out.print("\t");
    Arrays.stream(intermediate.dataElements).forEach(System.out::print);
    System.out.print("\t");
    Arrays.stream(destination.dataElements).forEach(System.out::print);
    System.out.print("\n");
}


private static void initialize(int number) {
    for(int i=number;i>0;i--) {
        source.push(i);
    }
}

private static void solveOdd(int number) {
    while(destination.top < number-1) {
        if(!movePlates(source, destination, intermediate)) {
            if(!movePlates(destination,intermediate,source)) {
                if(!movePlates(intermediate, source, destination)){
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}